# Searching for features?

Tags: software-recommendations, open-source-gis, references

With free, open source tools and data, I would like to be able to find (electronically, not by hand) properties (in the sense of "land owned by private individuals") that meet the following sample criteria:

- are 5 acres or greater in size
- are undeveloped and forested
- are flat or have predominantly north and/or west-facing slopes (that are not too steep)

Is there free, off-the-shelf software and data that can do this?

Or if not, can it be done through data manipulation or custom development?

What is the level of difficulty?

I seek answers, pointers toward resources, tutorials, or similar applications?

Answer (score 1):

The data is definitely available and free from the [USGS](http://landcover.usgs.gov/landcoverdata.php#na) or your state's GIS data warehouse. All you would need is a Land Cover raster, a block group or finer resolution census geodatabase(free from census.gov), and a DEM(Digital Elevation Model)raster. With QGIS you can create a slope raster from the DEM, assign the values from the Land Cover Raster and slope raster to census polygons, and query the layer's attributes as necessary.